# Can I replace what i write with '*' in the console in Python?

Tags: python, string, console

I am new to programming and I want to know if I can replace what I write when I run the program with '*'. For example if I write "password", I see in the console "********" but in the system it keeps being "password". I know that there is a way in C# but I don't find it in Python.

Comment: Have you considered the `getpass` module? It doesn't do exactly the same thing, but it does hide your password as it's being typed in the console.

Answer (score -2):

You can't replace it in the system, but you can replace it in the system output.
You could use the `print()` function to write the output to the screen, and you can use the string's `replace()` method to replace the desired characters with '*'s, like so:

```py
print('password'.replace('password', '*' * len('password')))
# ******
```

Comment: I don't see how this is useful in *any* sort of way. OP might as well do `print('******')`. This also does not answer the question. OP asks about taking input from a user